# The name of a poem about a poet being happy that someone has forgotten the title of their poem

Tags: poetry, identification-request

I read this poem in a collection and now I can't find it. It starts with the poet talking about how they were approached by someone who had loved one of their poems. But the reader could not remember the name of the poem.

This delighted the poet because, not only had the poem moved the reader, but someday they would rediscover it and be moved all over again as if they were reading it for the first time.

**Does anybody know the name of this poem, and the name of the poet?**

(P.S. Yes, I am aware of the irony here)

Comment: It's hard to Google for this one, because search terms like "poet reader forgotten name" just yield websites for identifying poems! +1 for meta :-D

Comment: It makes me think of [Nicanor Parra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicanor_Parra)'s [anti-poetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-poetry), but it's been a while, so, just a guess.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I actually found it myself. I remembered the collection I had read it in and searched through it. It is *The Secret* by Denise Levertov.

> Two girls discover
> the secret of life
> in a sudden line of
> poetry.
>
> I who don’t know the
> secret wrote
> the line. They
> told me
>
> (through a third person)
> they had found it
> but not what it was
> not even
>
> what line it was. No doubt
> by now, more than a week
> later, they have forgotten
> the secret,
>
> the line, the name of
> the poem. I love them
> for finding what
> I can’t find,
>
> and for loving me
> for the line I wrote,
> and for forgetting it
> so that
>
> a thousand times, till death
> finds them, they may
> discover it again, in other
> lines
>
> in other
> happenings. And for
> wanting to know it,
> for
>
> assuming there is
> such a secret, yes,
> for that
> most of all.

I realise now that I had the description a little bit wrong. That's the trouble with memory I suppose.