# Title of poem written by Causley after Macneice's funeral?

Tags: identification-request

I was told that Charles Causley wrote a poem on the way home from the funeral of Louis Macneice.  The fellow that mentioned it to me couldn't remember the title¹ but he wanted to read it again.

¹Perhaps this would [make Causley happy](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/3562/the-name-of-a-poem-about-a-poet-being-happy-that-someone-has-forgotten-the-title).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I believe it is called, rather unsurprisingly, *Death of a Poet*.** Firstly, the poem appeared in an anthology of poetry of his written between 1951 and 1975, and since MacNeice died in 1963, this is the right time frame. The [contents of this collection](https://books.google.com/books?id=UPwIAQAAIAAJ&dq=inauthor:%22Charles+Causley%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiI_42miZjbAhUstlkKHd8BDJ4Q6AEIUzAJ) as listed in Google Books includes *Death of a Poet* which seemed to me a reasonable title.

A search produced [this forum page](http://www.poetsgraves.co.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=121) which seems to confirm this and points to the Penguin Anthology *Worlds*, but I couldn't find this anthology:

> According to the notes in the Penguin anthology 'Worlds', [Causley's 'Death of a Poet']'s about Louis MacNiece *[sic]*.

On the other hand, the Causley Trust [also points to this same poem](http://causleytrust.org/charles-causleys-irish-influence-by-cahal-dallat/) saying

> Death of a Poet also reverberates with MacNeice, not just prescribing his own funeral and pallbearers, a common enough ‘folk’ thing to do, but with Charles’s the parson boomed echoing Louis’s My father made the walls resound/ He wore his collar the wrong way round…

Comment: Fun fact: Causley himself had a [poem entitled "Death of a Poet"](https://www.poetryarchive.org/poem/death-poet) written about him by a friend after his death. (I found this while hunting for the full text of Causley's own poem "Death of a Poet". Have you been able to find that?)

Comment: I did find the one about Causley but when I read the second quote, I was skimming and assumed it referred to that one.